# Mina and Devise.secret_key was not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mina

I'm trying to deploy my app with mina.
When it starts to run migrations I got this error:

```
-----> Migrating database
rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

  config.secret_key = 'key here.......'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
.........
```

In my devise initializer I have `config.secret_key = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]`

How to add this key to my app? 
Are secret_key_base and secret_key different?

This might be stupid but I dont know how to add this key.

Locally everything works fine

ps I'm using figaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'log', 'config/secrets.yml']
```

to my `deploy.rb` and it solved my problem.

In the `secrets.yml` I set `DEVISE_SECRET`

Answer (score 1):

open your rails app folder go to

config/initializers/devise.rb

and paste this line of code at the end:

```
config.secret_key = *****
```

where ***** is the string your console gives you when the error pops out.

as an Environment variable:

If you want an enviorment Variable you can go different ways, for example replace the above line of code to this:

```
config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']
```

then you can create a the variable on a keys.yml file and add it to your ./gitignore file.

after that you can import the yaml file to your app like this:

config/application.rb:

```
   ENV.update YAML.load(File.read(File.expand_path('../keys.yml', __FILE__)))
   module yourApp
     ...
     ...
   end
```

Comment: Is it ok to expose this code? It'll be visible on git. This is what I'm worried about.

Comment: If you are storing on git I would use an environment variable to store the key. ex: `ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']`

Comment: I store it in env var but when I deploy with mina it cant see this key.

Comment: sorry I somehow missed that part in your OP. In terminal just type `echo "export SECRET_KEY_BASE="insert key here" >> .bashrc`