# Rails 4: Devise.secret_key was not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise, asset-pipeline

This seems to be a popular issue, since I found many similar questions on Stack Overflow:

- [Devise Token Auth error: Devise.secret_key was not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089977/devise-token-auth-error-devise-secret-key-was-not-set)
- [Devise Secret Key was not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080910/devise-secret-key-was-not-set)
- [Mina and Devise.secret_key was not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951267/mina-and-devise-secret-key-was-not-set)

However, none of the above seems to help fix my problem.

Here is my situation:

1. I installed Font Awesome with the `font-awesome-rails` gem, and it was working locally, but whenever I deployed to Heroku, Font Awesome icons were no longer appearing.
2. So, I looked for answers to fix this problem, and found out that I needed to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to make things work.
3. However, when I run this command, I get the following error in Terminal:

`rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
config.secret_key = '—— MY_SECRET_KEY_HERE ———'
Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.`

As per the solutions offered in the questions mentioned at the beginning of my question, I do have`config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY'] if Rails.env.production?` in `devise.rb`

Also, [as recommended here](https://gist.github.com/taylor/10000885), I did run `heroku config:set DEVISE_SECRET_KEY='—— MY_SECRET_KEY_HERE ———' -- app name_of_my_app_here`.

Because I was not sure, I also ran `heroku config:set DEVISE_SECRET_KEY=—— MY_SECRET_KEY_HERE ——— -- app name_of_my_app_here` (without single quotes around my secret key).

But none of these things worked.

I keep getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can do a `heroku config -a app_name` to see what environment variables you have set. Devise should use your app's secret_key_base by default in Rails 4 applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have `SECRET_KEY_BASE` already set when I run the command you recommend. From there, what should I do next to try and fix my problem?

Comment: Did you try restarting your application? `heroku restart -a app_name`

Comment: Just tried it. Still get the same error message. I just noticed something: each time I get the error, the secret key suggested in the Terminal changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

Instead of keeping on struggling with the `font-awesome-rails` gem, I uninstalled it and replaced it with `font-awesome-sass`, which is the official Font Awesome gem for rails.

[Following the guidelines offered here](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) (section: ***EASY: SASS Ruby Gem***), I then ran `bundle` and added:

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

to my `application.scss` file.

I also removed the old `@import "font-awesome.css";` line from the very same file.

Now, Font Awesome works both locally and on Heroku.